# Is caching every database query healthy in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, caching, laravel

What I want to do is caching every database query into files. The queries will be cached with names including users' user names or user ids. Of course when a user changes its information, the cache file will be replaced with the new one. Even the interactons like friendship between users will be cached.

If I have 1.000.000 users, I will have millios (maybe billions) of files. Is this good or bad for the performance?

Comment: Have you measured your database's performance and found that it is slow? Do you have a million users and a billion files?

Comment: I am developing a social network script. I will not have billion files but the ones who will use the script may have. I think I must take every detail into consideration to increase performance.

Comment: Okay, but a million users is not very much to a computer. If you set up the database correctly then it should be faster than you need it to be. Optimizing stuff without knowing how your system will react may even make it slower. If you really want to optimize your system then you should create a million users and files, and then profile the system while under load (using XDebug, KCacheGrind/WinCacheGrind and [ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) for example).

Comment: I would start by not caching things - adding caches when you won't need them for a year or two can add complexity for no real benefit. Search for "premature optimisation" - it is a big topic in itself.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments. In my system, when a user visits a profile, the system will check whether they are friends. If not, it will check whether a request has been sent or got. And there are other small things. All these details require extra queries. I will start building one query including all these stuff but I will need a really complex query. Caching things has seemed to me an easy way.

Comment: If you are making a social network with Laravel then I recommend you watch Jeffrey Way's series "Larabook" on laracasts.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fill out your file system so it depends on the amount of space you have. Also, this would degrade performance based on the file lookups if you have a large number of active users.

In any case I would recommend using Memcache or APC as the laravel [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/cache) say.

Comment: In this case, I want to ask another question. Are file lookups are better or worse than mysql queries?

Comment: It all depends on the situation really. A database query is basically a file lookup as your data is stored on disk eventually(in most cases). When you have a very complex query(e.g. the database has to do a lot of work before the right results are returned), storing it in a file and loading the results from there could be faster. But I think there would not really be a benefit for caching a simple select where id = 1 with one result into a file. You should really test those situations to see wether the query would actually benefit by caching into a file.